# How to transform TS asserts condition in handy function?

Tags: typescript, enums, assert

I'm using asserts condition and have a code like this

```
enum Types { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c" }

type Entity = { type: Types };

assert(condition: any): asserts condition {
  if(!condition) throw new Error();
}

function abc(entity: Entity) {
  assert(entity.type === Types.a || entity.type === Types.b);
  ...
}

function def(entity: Entity) {
  assert(entity.type === Types.b || entity.type === Types.c);
  ...
}

function ghi(entity: Entity) {
  assert(entity.type === Types.c);
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to make compact generic assertion function to use like this and get the same assertion type checks?

```
assertType(entity, [Types.a, Types.b]);
```

Comment: @wonderflame No, it doesn't work because it doesn't decrease the type size. T[] will decide that type type is Types. We already know about it.

Also there is should be `types.every((type) => type !== arg)` inside function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to this question gave me an idea of solution.

```
function checkObjectType<
    T extends { type: unknown }, 
    X, 
    Y = never, 
    Z = never
>(obj: T, types: readonly [X, Y?, Z?]): obj is S & { type: X | Y | Z } {
    return types.some((type) => type === obj.type;
}


// Then I can write code like this.
function abc(entity: Entity) {
  assert(checkObjectType(entity, [Types.a, Types.b] as const));
  ...
  // in Runtime we check assertion and get only types a and b here
  // in Compiletime TS knows that only types a and b can be expected here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your function to 2 or 3 arguments by doing something like this :

```js
enum Types {
  a = "a",
  b = "b",
  c = "c",
}

function assertType<T, U>(v: unknown, types: [T, U]): asserts v is T | U {
  if (v!==types[0] && v!==types[1]) throw new Error("Failed condition")
}

const typeToTest = Types.a;

assertType(typeToTest, [Types.a, Types.b]); // PASS
assertType(typeToTest, [Types.a, Types.c]); // PASS
assertType(typeToTest, [Types.b, Types.c]); // FAIL
```

However I don't think it's possible to extend it to an indefinite number of values in the array. It means you must have one function to test for 1 type, one function to test for 2 types...

Comment: FYI TS supports optional values in tuple. So in theory it is okay to have one function with [T, S?, N?, M?]